How to show a point is a weak* -weak continuous for the identity map on $X_1^*$ or on $X_1^{**}$?
I am trying to understand the Remark 3.2 mentioned in the paper titled as "On Weak*
-Extreme Points in Banach Spaces" written by S. Dutta and T. S. S. R. K. Rao (http://library.isical.ac.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10263/3039/1/on%20weak%20extreme.pdf).
$\textbf{I am not able to understand the statement:}$ If $\Lambda \in \partial_eX_1^{***}$ is a point of weak* - weak continuity for the identity map on $X_1^{***}$ then again by the denseness of $X_1^*$ in $X_1^{***}$ we have that $\Lambda = x^*\in \partial_eX_1^{*}$.
Here, $X_1$ refers to the closed unit ball of the Banach space $X$ and $\partial_eX_1$ refers to the set of extreme points of $X_1$. $X_1^*$ refers to the closed unit ball of the dual space of $X$.
Also, I am having difficulty understanding the following example from the same paper.
$\textbf{Example:}$ Let $K$ be a compact set and $k_0\in K$ be an accumulation point. Since $\chi_{k_0}\in C(K)^{**}$ it is easy to see that $\delta (k_0)\in \partial_e C(K)_1^*$ is not a point of weak-weak continuity for the identity map on $C(K)_1^*$. However, since $\delta (k_0)$ is a denting point, it is a weak-denting point of $C(K)_1^{***}$ and hence is a point of weak-weak (in fact weak-norm) continuity for the identity map on $C(K)_1^{***}$.

I am not able to understand how to show a point is a weak*-weak continuous point for the identity map defined on the said domain.

How easily they can conclude a point is not a weak*-weak continuous point in the above example.

How to conclude a weak* denting point becomes a point of weak*-weak continuous point for the identity map in the above example?


Please help me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Unlike the title (with the whole space), the actual question is for the unit ball.

Thank you for the suggestion. Sorry for my mistake. I am going to edit the question accordingly. Can you please explain something about my queries if possible?
